# Since Ubuntu disables the root account by default, why not disable root shell access also?

Tags: command-line, security, root

The current defaults for the root account in `/etc/passwd` is `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`.

Why not set it to `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/sbin/nologin`?

Comment: So that you can do `sudo -i`?

Comment: "disables the root account" is a bit of a loose description: what it really disables is *password-based authentication* of the root account

Comment: @AlexP indeed I have just tested it, sudo -i does not work with root set to /usr/sbin/nologin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If that were the case, you would only be able to run commands with `sudo` one at a time, but you would not be able to start a root shell.
A root shell is convenient in many cases, e.g. if you are planning to run multiple commands as root in a row.

Specifically, you could not run `sudo -i`, as AlexP noted. From `man sudo`:

```
-i, --login    Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.
```

Comment: Doesn't `sudo /bin/bash` work to do that?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni that would be more like `sudo -s` I think (a root shell, but not a root *login* shell). It's a good point though - and in fact `sudo -s` does seem to work even when root's shell is `/usr/sbin/nologin`

Comment: You can disable ``-i``, ``-s``, ``/bin/bash``, and so on by just allowing a whitelist of commands, see the documentation for the sudoers file. This is so fine grained, that it is for example possible to allow users to run ``/etc/init.d/someservice restart`` as root without allowing them to run ``/etc/init.d/someservice stop``. But the ubuntu default is just to set no password for ``root`` and allow admin users to do everything with sudo. Probably the rationale is a) more than one admin user and b) The admin user does not need remember a second password for the root account.

Answer (score 8):

Besides Alberto Santini's sudo answer, there's another (far better) answer. If root's shell is set to something that is not a shell, booting single user doesn't work. There's recovery in `sulogin` for things like non-extant shell or completely broken shell, but it will not work if the shell appears to be a valid shell but isn't actually a shell.

You can still `sudo` directly to get a shell by specifying the shell to `sudo` so it's not even good protection.